# Segmentation fault trying to overload << operator

Tags: c++, class, segmentation-fault

Beginning with C++, I've written that simple piece of code, which is designed to serve as a (very basic) logger. This is mainly to try overloading operators.

```
class Logger {

  public:
    Logger() : _has_logged_something(false) { };

    template <typename T>
    friend Logger& operator <<(Logger& logger, T const & value) {
      logger._has_logged_something = true;
      std::cerr << value;
      return logger;
    };

  private:
    bool _has_logged_something;

};
```

I need to remember when something has been loaded already, in the `_has_logged_something` instance variable. But this line is causing a very helpful `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` at runtime. Must be an obvious mistake, but I can't get it.

--

**Edit**

As this doesn't seem to be a problem with this piece of code, here is how it is used to avoid using singletons (probably not the best code ever, but anyway).

```
#ifndef _BORDERS_COMMON_LOGGER_LOGGER_HH_INCLUDED
#define _BORDERS_COMMON_LOGGER_LOGGER_HH_INCLUDED

#include "common/log/logger.hh"
#include "common/log/event.hh"

namespace {
  static borders::common::log::Logger* _global_logger = NULL;
}

namespace borders {

  namespace common {

    namespace log {

      inline bool is_global_instance_initialized() {
        return _global_logger != NULL;
      };

      inline Logger& get_global_instance() {
        if (_global_logger == NULL) _global_logger = new Logger;
        return *_global_logger;
      };

    } // namespace log

  } // namespace common

} // namespace borders

#define LOG_INFO() (borders::common::log::get_global_instance())

#define LOG_START()
#define LOG_STOP() \
  if (borders::common::log::is_global_instance_initialized()) \
    delete &borders::common::log::get_global_instance(); \
  else \
    (void) 0;

#endif // _BORDERS_COMMON_LOGGER_LOGGER_HH_INCLUDED
```

Given I try to run this with:

```
LOG_INFO() << "Foo" << "Bar"
```

Once again, the text gets written on console when I comment out the line I pointed out before.

Comment: what code are you running acctually?

Comment: Simply something like `someInstantiatedLogger << "Foo" << "Bar"`. This correctly gets written on console if I comment out the line `logger._has_logged_something = true;`.

Comment: for me this compile well, @Pierre please paste exactly what you are running

Comment: @computer, the problem is not at compile time.

Comment: and runs just fine as well, sorry, I should also mentioned this fact ofcourse

Comment: @Pierre it works See :http://ideone.com/ukyU7L

Comment: must be an error in what he is executing actually

Comment: @Pierre please paste the code you are running and causes run time error

Comment: @Pierre: if commenting out that line make it work, then the value of logger is invalid. The rest of the function doesn't touch the logger object so will execute OK with an invalid logger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got it!

I think. At least I have a guess

See, that line `logger._has_logged_something = true` is the only line that used the data of the class `logger`. So my guess is that the class is invalid

I mean that you didn't really create that class. For some reason it wasn't really allocated.

For example if you did:

```
Logger *log; // see - I didn't put any value to it!

(*log)<<value; // this will do a segmentation fault or something 
               // ONLY if you have the line logger._has_logged_something = true
```

This is just an example. There are other options like:

```
struct blah{
  blah(Logger &log):logger(log);
  Logger &logger;
};
blah func(){
  Logger log;
  return blah(log);
}
...
blah b=func(); // b has an invalid logger in it, because it was destroyed after func
blah.logger << value ; // will do a segmentation fault too
```

**Edit**

Just saw your edit. So it seems to be my first example. Specifically, I believe you did `LOG_STOP()` before you logged.

**Edit 2**

You have an intrinsic problem in your code. `LOG_STOP` deletes the logger, but **doesn't reset it to `NULL`**. So if you want to restart logging after that, the logger won't be recreated (as `get_global_instance` checks if the logger is `NULL` before deciding to create it).

Try changing `LOG_STOP` to set `_global_logger` to NULL and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Are you blindly guessing?

Comment: @Jefffrey - yes. And I believe I'm right too. At least, that's the only thing I can think of that would make a segfault here.

Comment: Yes, dereferencing a NULL pointer is invalid and, yes, in practice you're only like to get a crash if you attempt to access a member behind that pointer.

Comment: Which is weird, because without touching the code except for commenting out the line I pointed out, and adding a destructor, the latter gets called as expected when calling the `LOGGER_STOP()` macro... I'm definitely missing something here.

Comment: @Pierre - I did another edit. Look at it. The problem isn't the destructor - the problem is that after calling `LOG_STOP()` you don't set the `_global_logger` back to `NULL`.

Comment: @Pierre you didn't show that you are calling LOG_STOP() ! please show exact code next time, it will be really easier to help you